# Laravel passing data into view

Tags: php, laravel

Not able to pass data to my view from controller.

My view is called "about.blade.php"
from my controller I simply  wrote

```
return view('pages.about')->with('fullname', "test");
```

My view is called "about.blade.php"
from my controller I simply  wrote  return view

```
$first = 'B';
$last = "Z";

$full = $first " " . $last;


return view('pages.about')->with('fullname', $full);
```

I expected to see the word concatenated text B Z on the page where I wrote {{fullname}}

I get the following error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_PARSE) syntax error, unexpected '" "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: use like this $full = $first. " " . $last;

Answer (score 2):

You also use `compact` to pass data into view like this :

```
return view('pages.about',compact('var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You must define a variable is correct in php `$fullname = $first . " " . $last;`
If you pass variables from controller to view, you have some method below:

```
return view('pages.about')->with('fullname', $fullname);

return view('pages.about', compact('fullname'));

$data['fullname'] = $fullname; 
return view('pages.about', $data);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

I left out the . for concatenation (:
 $full = $first . " " . $last;
thanks all can close.

Comment: Nice one. BTW - this is a perfect use case for `accessors` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators. See the `getFullNameAttribute` example. You define it once in your model and then use it throughout your code.

Comment: thank you will have a look into that (: & thank you Ivan.